# Can't request facebook's user_birthday

Tags: facebook, api

I received permission from facebook api to request user's birthday. So it's like everything is fine and in developers.facebook.com I can see, that user_birthday is live. Everything is fine till I request real permission on the web-site, then I can see that there are only public_profile, frienlist and email are requested.
What can be problem? Application is also live.

APP ID is 1564733130411506.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: is it approved? are you trying with a user who is admin/developer/tester in the app? what is your code?

Comment: It is approved. I'm trying to log in as regular user. But the APP is live, and user_birthday is live aswell.

Answer (score 0):

Has your app passed the Login Review regarding the `user_birhtday` permission? I guess not.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review

Comment: Do you pass it in the Login Url's scope parameter?